# FuelPHP on remote server

Tags: fuelphp

I am having a really hard time trying to get the FuelPHP to work with my remote server/ remote database. I know that they have Oil functionality that generates database tables for you but the issue is that I was only able to do it locally but not remotely.

Is there a tutorial or better way of trying to deploy or run FuelPHP on my remote server. I have seen a bunch of tutorials that are helpful for local server but I have not found anything for creating sites on remote server.

Maybe I am going about this in a wrong way or something but I am frustrated and confused. I just want to get it to work on my remote server as it does on my local server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use migrations to create and modify your database schema. It allows you to change the schema and rollback if needed, using `oil refine migrate`.

Using it implies however that you have commandline access to your remote server. If it's one of those cheap ftp-only hosting options, you've got a challenge. You can create a controller that uses the Migrate class to run migrations, which you can call from the browser after you've ftp'd the updated code to the server.

If you go this route, make sure you secure it properly!

Comment: Thank you but I believe we have already discussed this on FuelPHP Forum or I had finally figured it out myself. Either way, I solved my problem sometime last week.

Thank you again!

Comment: I know. I just wanted to be complete for people finding this page on a search.